# Returning 0 if value is NULL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, null, coalesce

```
SELECT
    p.id
  , ig.NumReceived
  , og.NumShipped
  , coalesce(
        (p.StartingInventory - og.NumShipped + ig.NumReceived),
        p.StartingInventory
      ) as OnHand
  , p.ProductName
  , p.StartingInventory
  , p.MinimumRequired
FROM
  products p
        left outer join (
            select productid, sum(NumReceived) as NumReceived
            from incoming
            group by productid
        ) as ig on p.id = ig.productid
        left outer join (
            select productid, sum(NumberShipped) as NumShipped
            from outgoing
            group by productid
        ) as og on p.id = og.productid
```

I managed to get `coalesce()` to function correctly in this statement for `(p.StartingInventory-og.NumShipped+ig.NumReceived)` but my intention is to return `0` if `ig.NumReceived` or `og.NumShipped` return `0` as well. By which I mean, retrieving `NumShipped` or `NumReceived` will display `0`. `coalesce((p.StartingInventory-og.NumShipped+ig.NumReceived)` works as it should but the line i'm referring to is `ig.NumReceived, og.NumShipped`

I've also tried `IFNULL()`. I've tried encompassing just the `ig.NumReceived` as well as the select statement. I'm using MySql 5.7.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was

```
SELECT
    p.id
  , coalesce(ig.NumReceived, 0) as NumReceived
  , coalesce(og.NumShipped, 0) as NumShipped
  , coalesce(
        (p.StartingInventory - og.NumShipped + ig.NumReceived),
        p.StartingInventory
      ) as OnHand
  , p.ProductName
  , p.StartingInventory
  , p.MinimumRequired
FROM
  products p
        left outer join (
            select productid, sum(NumReceived) as NumReceived
            from incoming
            group by productid
        ) as ig on p.id = ig.productid
        left outer join (
            select productid, sum(NumberShipped) as NumShipped
            from outgoing
            group by productid
        ) as og on p.id = og.productid;
```

Answer (score 0):

> my intention is to return 0 if ig.NumReceived or og.NumShipped return 0 as well

If so, convert

```
coalesce((p.StartingInventory-og.NumShipped+ig.NumReceived), p.StartingInventory) as OnHand
```

to, for example,

```
coalesce(  p.StartingInventory - og.NumShipped + ig.NumReceived,
           case when ig.NumReceived = 0 or og.NumShipped = 0 
                then 0 
                else p.StartingInventory 
                end               
        ) as OnHand
```

Comment: To clarify, I mean for `og.NumShipped` or `ig.NumReceived`, `OnHand` works as intended but I intend to retrieve and display `og.NumShipped` and `ig.NumReceived` individually.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex conditional expressions, use a CASE expression:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

The documentation for MySQL describes CASE expressions as part of the control flow topic, since the same CASE keyword is also used for conditional statement execution. The documentation is overly concise, and in the wrong place IMHO :-)
CASE expressions are extremely useful feature.

SQL Server's documentation for CASE expressions is more elaborate, and the syntax is the same as MySQL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql